# Error al importar PyQt5 en python

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

El siguiente codigo compilaba perfectamente antes de formatear mi laptop. Instale W10 descasgue Python 3.8.1 y pues luego (pip install PyQt5)Ahora el codigo no compila y me tira un error en las primeras lieas donde se cargan las librerias.

El error dice:

> ImportError: DLL load failed while importing QtWidgets: %1 no es una aplicación Win32 válida.

```
import sys
import sqlite3
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication,QMainWindow,QWidget,QPushButton,QLineEdit


class Ventana(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Ventana,self).__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle("Ventana")
        self.setGeometry(250,250,450,300)
        self.show()



if __name__=="__main__":
    aplicacion = QApplication(sys.argv)
    Vn = Ventana()
    sys.exit(aplicacion.exec_())
```

Comment: ¿Cuando instalaste python habilitaste el checkbox que habilitaba la capacidad de añadir la ruta de python a las variables del entorno?

Comment: Si, lo instale todo como de constumbre

Comment: Okay, entonces busca en la carpeta donde se instalo PyQt5  la carpeta donde estan los .dll de pyqt5 y añade ese directorio al PATH de las variables de entorno.

Comment: Ya lo hice, igual da el mismo problema. Este problema comenzo cuando installe qtcharts (pip install) inmediatamente despues de eso. Como no me queria quebrar la cabeza formatee la laptop pero el problema sigue y es exactamente el mismo.

Comment: Es como si cambiaron algo y se ha manifestado luego de la nueva instalación (actualización) porque en el código: import PyQt5, no da error, pero si: from PyQt5 import QMainWindow,QPushButton, si aparece el error.

Comment: `import PyQt5` no hace literalmente nada, es decir no carga ninguna funcionalidad por ello no falla, puedes decirme que contiene el PATH de las variables de entorno. Por otro lado prueba instalando una version anterior de pyqt5 y/o python

Comment: Bueno la única forma que conozco de instalar PyQt5 es (pip install PyQt5) y esa no me deja escoger versiones anteriores. Instale todo en otra laptop que nada sabia de python y toda esa parafernalia de desarrollo y me da el mismo problema. Toda la instalación la he hecho de manera correcta, los problemas con el PATH ya los he tenido y los he resuelto. Esto es simplemente un problema que apareció de la nada prácticamente, no he cambiado nada del código y la instalación es exactamente la misma que he realizado desde que uso python 3 y PyQt5.

Comment: Bueno, parece que estas estresado por lo que seguir una discusión es improductiva, adios. Solo una última cosa: pip si permite instalar versiones anteriores: `python -m pip install pyqt5==5.13.0` por ejemplo

Comment: Hermano agradezco tu paciencia. Si desde el principio hubiera intentado con instalar una versión anterior de pyqt5, me diste la solución . Pero el problema aun sigue porque tarde o temprano deberé usar la actualización.

Comment: Prueba actualizando pip: `python -m pip install --upgrade pip` y luego instalas pyqt5: `python -m pip install pyqt5`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parece que para las versiones recientes de PyQt5 es necesario tener actualizado pip(parece que ha habido cambios en setuptools), en SOen respondi preguntas similares [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60287884) y [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59711301), por lo que la solucion es actualizar pip y reinstalar pyqt5:

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
python -m pip install pyqt5
```